# What is the correct way to use and reference partial templates when sending emails with FluentEmail?

Tags: c#, .net, razor, razor-pages, fluent

I am using FluentEmail library in a .NET 6 project and it's working fine for most of what I need it to do.

I have a layout file _DefaultEmailLayout.cshtml that contains a basic header and footer, so in one of my template files ForgotPassword.cshtml i reference this layout file.

```
@model SharedLibrary.Models.Shared.EmailTemplate

@{
     Layout = Model.LayoutLocation; //contains location of layout file
}

<tr>
    <td class="mceBlockContainer" valign="top" style="background-color:#ffffff; padding-top:21px; padding-bottom:7px; padding-right:25px; padding-left:25px">
        <div class="mceText" id="dataBlockId-40" style="width:100%">
            <p class="last-child">
                <strong>Your password</strong>
            </p>
        </div>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td class="mceBlockContainer" valign="top" style="background-color:#ffffff; padding-top:7px; padding-bottom:40px; padding-right:25px; padding-left:25px">
        <div class="mceText" id="dataBlockId-25" style="width:100%">
            <p>Hi @Model.FirstName,</p>
        </div>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td class="mceBlockContainer" valign="top" style="background-color:#ffffff; padding-top:21px; padding-bottom:7px; padding-right:25px; padding-left:25px">
        <div class="mceText" id="dataBlockId-40" style="width:100%">
            <p class="last-child">
                <strong>Need Help?</strong>
            </p>
        </div>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td class="mceBlockContainer" valign="top" style="background-color:#ffffff; padding-top:7px; padding-bottom:40px; padding-right:25px; padding-left:25px">
        <div class="mceText" id="dataBlockId-25" style="width:100%">
            <p>
            </p>
            <p class="last-child">
                If you need any assistance, our Client Support Team are here to help. Feel free to reach out to our team via email on XXX
            </p>
        </div>
    </td>
</tr>
```

And in the code itself when I use the FluentEmail.UsingTemplateFromFile().SendAsync() it sends the email successfully and the email is received looking as expected with the layout files header and footer.

What I'm having trouble with is that a few of my emails share a section that you see in the ForgotPassword.cshtml file, the Need Help section, so instead of duplicating it in all those files I placed it in a separate file called _NeedHelpLayout.cshtml

Now if I replace that section in ForgotPassword.cshtml with the below then when the email sends, the section is not only not parsed but it's not anywhere to be found, the email template just doesn't include it. Am I doing something wrong here?

```
<partial name="xxx" />
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the Razor renderer in the FluentMail then the template renderer is RazorLight engine not the MS Razor engine.That means and the partial tag is ignored. Instead, use the IncludeAsync method from RazorLight engine (see the [docs](https://github.com/toddams/RazorLight#includes-aka-partial-views) of RazorLight for details).
In the template file :

1. Add at the top
   `@using RazorLight`
2. And where was supposed to be the partial tag, put this :
   `@{ await IncludeAsync("path_to_the_partial_view.cshtml", Model);}`